# xsl date format transformation

Tags: date, xslt, format

I've created a javacode to transform an xml to other formatted xml, which is working fine, but I can not format the date. I need to convert this:

2015-01-02T17:20:00-05:00

to format

Mon, 05 Jan 2015 21:57:56 GMT

I do the transformation with this code:

```
public void transform(File dataXML, File inputXSL, File outputXML)
throws TransformerConfigurationException,
TransformerException
{
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource(inputXSL);
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslStream);
    StreamSource in = new StreamSource(dataXML);
    StreamResult out = new StreamResult(outputXML);
    transformer.transform(in, out);
    System.out.println("The generated XML file is:" + outputXML);
}
```

Comment: It depends on you environment. If you're using XSL2.0, you can use built in XPath functions for date and time, for example fn:hours-from-dateTime

Comment: I added the java code

Comment: Since you're using Java, it shouldn't be too difficult to move to Saxon 9 processor which supports XSLT 2.0.  The solution in XSLT 1.0 is *much* more complex.